# Can I copy a fragment of the input XML using NSXMLParserDelegate protocol?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

Using the NSXMLParserDelegate protocol for parsing XML is fine, however I have the need to copy verbatim a chunk of XML in an answer. What I would like to do is store everything between the beginning/end XML tags verbatim as an NSString object so I can *replay* this fragment in a future query.

Is this possible or the only solution is parsing the tree manually, converting to a temporal object, then back to XML string in the future query?

One thing to note is that I'm not parsing incrementally the input, rather I'm creating the `NSXMLParser` object with the complete xml data, then calling `parse` on it. So maybe there's a way to correlate the position of `didStartElement`/`didEndElement` inside the original xml data so I can extract the subrange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `didStartElement` and `didEndElement` are being passed an `NSXMLParser` which tracks the progress of the parsing through the `lineNumber` and `columnNumber` properties. Unfortunately there's no direct way to transform those line/column info to a buffer offset, but then as well you have to interpret the `NSData` with a specific encoding.

A solution is to transform the `NSData` into a buffer of unichar elements with the `NSString::getCharacters:range: method`. Then the unichar buffer can be iterated scanning for newline elements until a match of line/col is found against the values stored by the `NSXMLParser` object. Doing this for the start/end tags gets you the unichar range of characters of XML contained inside them.

Now this range can be transformed to an `NSString` and that be reused in future queries. The advantage of this is that the XML inside doesn't require to be *parsed* since it is copied directly and is expected to be well formed.